# php include file extension

Tags: php, lamp

I often see examples in PHP that use .inc files to include but I can't connect to my MySQL server in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using LAMP. I have also used .php in my file to include but it does not still connect.

What is the meaning of .inc? What is it used for? How different is it from .php? Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no actual difference; it's simply a naming convention that some people use.  A `.inc` file is `include`d or `require`d from a PHP file, and the file being pulled in is expected to itself by PHP.

Comment: If I get you clearly, then the problem I'm facing is not from file extension since there's no difference in using either .inc or .php right?